# Unexpected result when binding Asp.NET repeater with user control with filtered List<class>

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, repeater

I have a page with a repeater control which has a user control and a button. I bind the user control with a list of objects. I have a dropdownlist of classifiers and on selecting a classifier repeater is loaded with filtered set of values. All fine till now.

The problem is when I click the button to retrieve the values, the value of hiddenfield comes up fine but not the value in other labels.

For example, when YYY classifier is selected, the repeater is populated with values corresponding to YYY. But when I click the button in that repeater, I get the value of hf as 3, but value from label as ABC.

```
//Class used to bind
public class Test
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String classifier { get; set; }
}

static List<Test> testlist = null;
//page load
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    testlist = new List<Test>
    {
         new Test{ID=1, Name="ABC", classifier="XXX"},
         new Test{ID=2, Name="DEF", classifier="XXX"},
         new Test{ID=3, Name="GHI", classifier="YYY"}
    }
}

//Binding repeater
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
    e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var obj = e.Item.DataItem as Test;
        var control = e.Item.FindControl("Items") as WebUserControl;
        var lblName = control.FindControl("lblName") as Label;
        var lblClassifier = control.FindControl("lblClassifier") as Label;
        var lblID = control.FindControl("hfID") as Hiddenfield;
        lblName.Text = obj.Name;
        lblClassifier.Text = obj.classifier;
        lblID.Value = obj.ID.ToString();
}

//LINQ used to filter records
List<Test> tempList = testList.OfType<Test>().Where(x => x.classifier.Equals("YYY")).ToList();
```

Any direction towards a solution is appreciated. I guessed it might be life cycle issue, but the value of Hiddenfield is all fine and that confuses me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is "ABC" the original value of the Label (as set in markup)? If so, it could be a sign that the ViewState is disabled. That would affect the value of the Labels but not the value of input controls (TextBoxes, HiddenFields, etc.).

Comment: No. I am populating "ABC" as shown in repeater bound event. And I also tried enabling the ViewStateMode of label. Still the same.

Comment: Yes. The repeater is populated from a user control which has ViewStateEnabled as true.

Comment: I had a hiddenfield with same value as Label and as you mentioned it did work. But isn't there any way I can make label work ?

Comment: The only difference I see between the two types of controls is the ViewState. If `EnableViewState` is set to `false` at a higher level, enabling it for a control will not work. One way to test if the ViewState is enabled: (1) add a Button and a Label to the form, (2) modify the Label text in `Page_Load` inside an `if (!IsPostBack)` condition. Once the application is loaded, the modified text should appear in the Label. After clicking the Button to cause a postback, if the Label text reverts to its original value, the ViewState is disabled.